# Which is better approach in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

First Appraoch

```
   /\
  /  \
V/    \ C <=WCF=> {Business Layer (with business logic) <=> ORM <=> Database}
/      \
--------
    M
```

Second Approach

```
   /\
  /  \
V/    \ M <=WCF=> {Business Layer (with business logic) <=> ORM <=> Database}
/      \
--------
    C
```

Main Difference:
- In first approach, business object will have 2 versions. One loaded with properties inside business layer and other dumb version with few View specific properties to be populated by Controller. While in second appraoch, there will be one class with all properties.
- First approach seem a bit more decoupled from presentation layer

In both approach, Controller would be starting point.
As far from views I've recevied from different people, both are valid approaches and can be toggled as per development preference.
Please share thoughts.

Comment: Looks like your model layer is doing nothing in either case, acting more like 'View Models'.  I agree with alex - your model should contain your business logic. Models should contain information *and* behaviour that is related to the business domain.

Comment: Whats the difference between both of them? C is listening BL or M is listening BL. I would suggest creating ViewModel (VM) which wraps V & M.

Comment: MVC is a presentation aspect. If I use first option, I can switch between MVC or may be silverlight MVVM or other pattern easily as my business logic and core domain entities are intact. Model are not completely dumb in second approach. Controller would just instantiate model and model's contructor would actually talk to a business layer to get data for populating itself.

Comment: The model in MVC ***is*** your WCF service (or any other data source). It's a fact. There are no variations of that. Your second approach is not MVC.

Comment: Interestingly only people I could find still liking approach B (as they say controller should be dumb) are from JAVA world...

Comment: The controller should be dump. The only logic in it should be to take information from the model and adapt it for the view (and vice versa). It's the "glue" in MVC. ViewModels do not really belong in the MVC pattern. But without them you would have used a lot of magic strings representing the information to present (as Views should have no knowledge of the model and it's structure). VM just makes the information needed in the views typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one. ViewModels (as you refer as "M" in your triad) should not know of anything in the View or in your business layer.

The real MVC definition:

- Model: Business layer, webservice or whatever.
- View: UI
- Controller: Glue between the Model and the View.

Microsoft added the ViewModel to make the separation more clear. For starters, the view shouln't be dependent of your domain models. And it should not contain logic.

I've listed the main reasons to use view models here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/three-reasons-to-why-you-should-use-view-models/

Comment: viewmodels aren't worth the trouble unless you're dealing with multiple "view" layers, since all the work could (and should) be done by the model itself. with multiple "view" layers, on the other hand, you need them or you won't be able to come up with the right kind of "model" for the task. ultimately, whatever works and can be easily mantained/updated works, anyway.

Comment: Great if that works for you. That doesn't work for me since then I tend to add logic into my views. Mostly small things like showing a default text if a property is null. All those small changes get's duplicated in all views that use a model and finally becomes a big mess that's hard to maintain. By using view models I keep those changes in one place and my views are clean.

Comment: I too like the idea of having separate viewmodels.However, what's the performance hit in casting domain object to viewmodel object in controller layer?

Comment: I can promise you that I could find ten more important performance issues in your code. Those object costs are minimal.

Comment: lol. Just like nice article above, do you have any performance article on ASP.NET MVC... However you made me curious that what those 10 issues could be :)

Comment: I'm just saying that creating small object should be the last thing that you should worry about. There will always be other things that will affect performance more. I always use view models and AutoMapper to copy information from the domain model to the view model.

Answer (score 3):

We are using next approach in asp.net mvc applications:

- ViewModels - flat objects that aggregate information for view rendering
- Controllers - build ViewModels from business objects (that have logic inside them or that are generated by ORM)
- Model - business objects that aren't available in view

View <- ViewModel <- Controller <-BusinessObject <- Db

You can get more details about this approach from [Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470292784)

Comment: I understand  jgauffin has also favoured this approach. Just for final clarification, for example, there is a WCF layer with all logic integrated and interacting with a database via ORM, So it will be considered as the Model which controller would use to populate ViewModels? thanks

Answer (score 1):

imho Business logic belongs to Models. Controllers shouldn't know nor care about why you want something displayed in your Views.

In fact, i think it's a matter of what's best for the job here, more than an absolute "best".